# How to kill all processes from a user using GPU?

Tags: kill

How do I kill all processes from a user using GPU? E.g.

```
killall --gpu --user kong
```

Comment: Where did you get `--gpu` flag for killall? Manpage even in 21.10 [does not mention it](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/en/man1/killall.1.html).

Comment: If you are using nvidia-smi, you may be able to do something like this: [How to kill all processes using a given GPU?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250244/how-to-kill-all-processes-using-a-given-gpu)

Comment: @N0rbert its an example

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using GPU, you can try a one liner like this:

```
for i in $(ps axu | tr -s " "  | grep "^kong" | cut -d " " -f 2); do sudo kill -9 $i, ; done
```

Here, I'm getting all processes belonging to a user and forcing them to be terminated by sending them a kill signal. I assumed the username is kong.